# What are subsets of $A\times B$ called?

Tags: notation, relations

What are subsets of $A\times B$ called in mathematics?

- In logic (algebra and analysis), a **binary relation** on/over $A$ is a subset of $A^2$. Abstractions of $=$, $\leq$, etc. While using subsets of $A\times B$ extensively in the role of *functor*, logicians have no term for these objects. I have always called a subset of $A\times B$ a *binary relation**ship***, but always explain that this is just my term.
- In the computer science ER Model, a **binary relation** is a subset of $A\times B$, with a subset of $A^2$ being called a **recursive** *binary relation*.

Wikipedia currently makes a complete mess of the situation, by defining a [binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation)  as

> In mathematics, a binary relation over two sets $X$ and $Y$ is a set of
>   ordered pairs $(x, y)$ consisting of elements $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$. That
>   is, it is a subset of the Cartesian product $X × Y$.

yet defining an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), via reference to the above definition, as

> In mathematics, an equivalence relation is a binary relation that is
>   reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

The latter definition is complete nonsense for subsets of $A\times B$, only making sense for subsets of $A^2$. Reflexivity cannot be defined for subsets of $A\times B$.

- What are subsets of $×$ called in mathematics?
- I have never encountered these being called binary relations in mathematics, except for Wikipedia. I thought this might be my algebra-logic bias, but have checked Analysis books, and yes, (binary) **relations** are as we have known them from primary school, subsets of $A^2$. Abstraction of $=$, $\leq$, etc.
- Unary operations ($o:A\rightarrow A$) are to binary relations ($r\subseteq A^2$) as functions ($f:A\rightarrow B$) are to ??? ($R\subseteq A\times B$)?

I am not looking for a proposed term, nor asking for reference back to Wikipedia, rather, I am asking if there is some term **already** in widespread use in the literature, and ideally with reference.

---

Based on answers received so far, an additional question would then be,

- in the context that binary relations are subsets of $A\times B$, what term distinguishes the $A^2$ case? Endomorphic? Recursive?

---

Some have argued that the Wikipedia definition of equivalence relation is correct as stands. It is not. The definition of an equivalence relation cannot be phrased for subsets of $A\times B$. Reflexivity is impossible to define for subsets of $A\times B$. Further, no one would define an equivalence relation as a subset of $A\times B$ such that..., and then expect the reader to deduce that $A$ must equal $B$. No. That is not how equivalence relations are defined. Currently Wikipedia is wrong.

---

@TheEmptyFunction has drawn my attention to the fact that Wikipedia currently defines an $n$-ary [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) as a function $A_1\times...\times A_n\rightarrow B$, rather than the mathematicians $A^n\rightarrow A$. This definition strips the notion of operation of *all* its logical/algebraic/analytic meaning. Homomorphisms no longer make sense. The same is true for calling a subset of $A\times B$ a binary relation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all math, you have to be sensitive to the context - different fields are going to use slightly different terms depending on their needs, and will often use terminology from other fields imprecisely via metaphor. You shouldn't assume that every mathematician means the exact same formal definition as every other mathematician by such terms, especially when it comes down to small details like domain/codomains, and distinctions like those between objects like "a boolean valued function on a set" and "a subset of a set" where mathematicians often differ in the precise details (and may even just treat them as interchangeable).

This said, I think all the evidence you need is in your question: subsets of $A\times B$ are most commonly known as *relations* from $A$ to $B$ (with this "from _ to _" phrasing mostly coming from [the category Rel](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Rel) - in some contexts where order doesn't matter you'll hear "between _ and _" instead). There are some other terms that sometimes get used (e.g. "binary predicate" which is subtly different, but interchangeable in most classical contexts - note that predicates commonly take any number of arguments, so "binary" is important here) as well as some qualifiers (e.g. "binary relation" to clarify that two sets are involved in the product). In my experience, this term is very widespread (and Wikipedia would not invent a name for a concept like this!), but not so technical as to have everyone in agreement about the specifics - sort of like how $\mathbb N$ might include $0$ or might not, but it's should never be hard to figure out which convention the author meant or if it matters.

The definition of an equivalence relation does not contradict this definition of a relation. An equivalence relation *is* a (binary) relation, but the properties of symmetry, transitivity, and reflexivity all implicitly assume that it is a relation from a set to itself. This is in the same way that an *endomorphism* is a kind of function where the domain and codomain are equal.

Comment: What mathematical term distinguishes recursive/endormorphic binary relations from others? Recursive? Endomorphic?

Comment: @fundagain It's not a sufficiently common mathematical idea to have a universally understood term. The clearest thing to say is "a relation from a set to itself" or occasionally you'll hear "a relation on a set" (which is imprecise, but easily understood) or, in the category Rel "an endomorphism." Sometimes those objects might be thought of as directed graphs. It's an issue of language and intuition - you seem to be after rigorous answers, but it's important to know that common mathematical language is not itself rigorous - it is merely meant to convey rigorous ideas.

Comment: I would just like to check that I have got you right. Binary relations as subsets of $A^2$ *are* universally understood. Binary relations as subsets of $A \times B$ are *not* a universally understood term. Hence I should not expect a universal term for the *latter* notion. This is consistent with everything I have read over my life. I was hoping there *was* a term, because it would make my life easier. But a term for subsets of $A \times B$ that is *not* "relation".

Comment: @fundagain It's the other way around: a binary relation from $A$ to $B$ is a subset of $A\times B$ - just like Wikipedia says. Subsets of $A\times A$ are a special case of this more general definition and are often called relations *on* $A$ (...or spoken of in entirely different terms, e.g. in the language of directed graphs or binary predicates).

Comment: No you are right. It is used that way.

Comment: Are unary operations $A\rightarrow A$ now also conflated with functions $A\rightarrow B$?

Comment: @fundagain A unary operation is a kind of function (in particular, it is a function in which the domain equals the codomain).

Comment: Not according to Wikipedia. Operations are now defined as like we are now doing for relations: an operation ω is a function of the form ω : V → Y, where V ⊂ X1 × ... × Xk. The sets Xk are called the domains of the operation, the set Y is called the codomain of the operation, and the fixed non-negative integer k (the number of arguments) is called the type or arity of the operation.

Comment: @fundagain Again, you shouldn't expect that notation is absolutely consistent across users - if you pull notation from different places, you're going to find different definitions, like that, which is very broad (and serves an elementary viewpoint, treating division as an operation) - though note that you cannot reasonably claim that "a unary operation $A\rightarrow A$" means "a function $V\rightarrow Y$ where..." because you wrote $A\rightarrow A$, which is explicit. In any case, this line of comments is not really on-topic, as it addresses something other than what the answer does.

Answer (score 4):

"Wikipedia makes a complete mess ... " is just a trifle arrogant, because Wikipedia, as quoted, gets it exactly right.

A binary relation on $A, B$ cannot be symmetric unless $A = B$, so "equivalence relations" (as defined) are all on products of the form $A \times A$; they are exactly those relations that are symmetric, transitive, and reflexive.

"While using subsets of × extensively in the role of functor," ... I certainly hope you mean "function"; functors are defined on categories (or at least they were back in the 1980s, when I learned this stuff).

"I have never encountered these being called binary relations in mathematics, except for Wikipedia." says more about the extent of your exposure to mathematics than it does about Wikipedia.

Halmos's "Naive Set Theory" does a pretty good job getting this stuff laid out without too much fuss. Of course it doesn't mention functors, but that's because it's a naive-set-theory book.

Comment: Am I to take from your answer that it is well-known that binary relations are defined as subsets of $A\times B$, and that subsets of $A^2$ are special cases called [what]? What is the term that distinguishes the latter from the former. Is it "recursive" as in computer science?

Comment: No! How do you define reflexive over $A\times B$?

Comment: No I mean functor. The algebraization of a logic, if it exists, take a point/formula to a *set* of points/formulae. These point-set functions give rise to binary relations rather than functions.

Comment: 1. "reflexive", when applied to a relation, also requires that the two sets be the same. 2. What you mean by "functor" is apparently not what category theorists, for example, mean by "functor," for the "domains" in category may be too large to be sets. 3. Is it well known that (binary) relations are subsets of cartesian products. Well, that's how the much-cited Halmos book defines them. A random discrete math book I just grabbed (Maurer and Ralston) has that definition on page 18. The more widely used book by Rosen delays that to page 355, but says the same thing. So....yeah. Well-known.

Comment: As for relations on $A,A$ (i,e, a subset of $A \times A$) I'd call that a "binary relation on $A$", and I'd expect no one to be confused by it, but I've been wrong before. :)

Comment: Yes. You are right. It seems relation that way is wide spread. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I really mean functor in the category sense. Category theory also works for non class domains! When considering the "morphisms" between logics without equality, particularly logics with only relation symbols, binary relations work better than functions, i.e., it is better to consider such systems in cat-rel rather than cat-func.

Comment: I *really* don't think anyone other than Wikipedia defines an equivalence relation as a subset of $A\times B$. Can you with a straight face define an equivalence relation to your students as a subset of $A\times B$ :)

Comment: I don't think Wikipedia *does* define it that way. You and I are evidently reading it differently.

Comment: Yes. We must read reflexivity as demanding that $A=B$, then it works.

Comment: You do see that a binary relation can be symmetric without $A=B$!

Answer (score 1):

Let A & B be sets. Then, a subset of $A \times B$ is referred to in different ways depending on what you're trying to accomplish.

For example, a relation is any subset of $A \times B$. Unless I'm blanking and missing out on something, that's the coarsest structure that you're working with. Just plain old subsets of $A \times B$. We just call those relations.

Then, you could take it one step higher and say that a function is a subset of $A \times B$ such that $\forall a \in A: \exists! b \in B: (a,b) \in f$, where $f:A \to B$ is the function.

Notice that we have created an entirely new term based on an additional property that we've imposed on the specific subset of $A \times B$ that we pick out. These are just additional properties that would make them interesting to study.

For example, Linear Transformations are specific functions that map elements from one vector space to another vector space such that an additional number of conditions hold. In this case, the function itself has to specify certain properties and the sets also have to satisfy specific properties.

Definition: A binary operation on a set $S$ is a function $\circ: S \times S \to S$

In other words, a binary operation is nothing but a function of a specific type. It takes two elements from S, does something to them and spits out something that belongs to S.

To put it very simply, they are referred to in different ways depending on the context.

**References:**

Fundamentals of Mathematics by Bernd Schroder

Comment: Might e.g. call $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ "the unit square".... or "the limits of our integal", or a whole lot of other names

Comment: Indeed. Context dictates the name of a given set.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the context, a subset of $A\times B$ may be called a binary relation or simply referred to as a subset of $A\times B$.

For example, if I am referring to a particular subset $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$ then I might want to think of it more geometrically as opposed to being a relation on $\mathbb{R}$ (although it is technically a binary relation). For example, the unit circle is the subset $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$. But I could equivalently think of it as a relation $x\sim y$ if and only if $x^2+y^2=1$.

The way that we can go back and forth between subsets $R\subseteq A\times B$ and binary relations is by the correspondence $(a,b)\in R\Longleftrightarrow a\sim b$.

As for your comment about equivalence relations, you are correct. The reflexivity requirement forces $A=B$. But there's nothing contradictory about that. It just means that if $A\neq B$, no subset of $A\times B$ is an equivalence relation.

I really do not understand what you are asking by saying "Operations are to binary relations as functions are to ???." Operations are functions $O:A_1\times\cdots\times A_n\to B$

Comment: I have corrected that to *unary* operations are to binary relations as functions are to ???.

Comment: A unary operation $O$ is just a function $O:A\to B$. 

Operations and functions are the same thing. Every operation is a function, and every function $f:X\to Y$ is a unary operation on $X$ with values in $Y$.

Comment: Yes. So unary operation is to binary relation as function is to ??? Or unary operation is to ??? as function is to binary relation.

Comment: Unary operations are the same thing as functions. And a function is just a specific type of binary relation. So unary operation is to binary relation as function is to binary relation. If P=Q, then P is to X as Q is to X (no matter what X is)

Comment: No. Unary operations are *special* functions.

Comment: What is an example of a function which is not a unary operation?

Comment: All $f:A\rightarrow B$ such that $A\neq B$

Comment: Why is that not a unary operation? What are you taking as the definition of an operation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)

Comment: That is not the way we define operation in algebra or logic. An operation ω is a function of the form ω : V → Y, where V ⊂ X1 × ... × Xk. The sets Xk are called the domains of the operation, the set Y is called the codomain of the operation, and the fixed non-negative integer k (the number of arguments) is called the type or arity of the operation. In algebra an operation is from $A^n$ back into $A$. Thats what I am talking about.

Comment: Sorry if you misunderstood.

Comment: I have made that clear in the OP. Tx.

Comment: I see no need to exclude the case when $A\neq B$. In algebra for example, there is the "operation" of going from an element to the subgroup it generates. $\langle -\rangle:G\to \wp(G),$ $g\mapsto \langle g\rangle$. Whether or not this truly counts as an operation is a matter of taste, although the current convention seems to say yes.

If you wish to exclude to case $A\neq B$, that is fine. Just make sure to be clear that's what you mean. In practice, context usually makes it clear what $B$ is anyways. It may be best to avoid the word operation altogether and simply say function $f:A^n\to A$

Comment: "Love" is a special case of "Like". So I see no reason not to exclude "like" from "love". So lets replace all instances of "like" with "love". Whateva :)